# Replace fillna value with the first non-zero value of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as following:

```
,VM,Storage Capacity MB,Memory Capacity MB,Powerstate,CPUs
0,abc1234,102400.0,4096,poweredOn,1

1,xyz1234,81920.0,4096,poweredOn,1

2,abc1234,,4096,poweredOff,1

3,xyz1234,,4096,poweredOff,1
```

Rows having NaN value need to replaced with non-zero first match. The output needs to following:

```
,VM,Storage Capacity MB,Memory Capacity MB,Powerstate,CPUs
0,abc1234,102400.0,4096,poweredOn,1

1,xyz1234,81920.0,4096,poweredOn,1

2,abc1234,102400.0,4096,poweredOff,1

3,xyz1234,81920.0,4096,poweredOff,1
```

Using `fillna.method('lasfil')` doesnt really replace with first match.

```
    import pandas 
    file2 = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\pd_powerstate_new_south.csv')
    file2 = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\pd_powerstate_new_south.csv')
    file1.set_index('VM')
    file2.set_index('VM')
    merged_data = pd.merge(left = file1, right = file2, how = 'outer')
    merged_data.fillna("some custom 
    method").to_csv(r'c:\temp\mergeddata.csv')
```

Acutal result needs to be following:

```
 ,VM,Storage Capacity MB,Memory Capacity MB,Powerstate,CPUs 0,abc1234,102400.0,4096,poweredOn,1
 1,xyz1234,81920.0,4096,poweredOn,1
 2,abc1234,102400.0,4096,poweredOff,1
 3,xyz1234,81920.0,4096,poweredOff,1
```

Comment: Is lasfil the same as bfill?

Answer (score 0):

You apparently want to do it by VM so you missed a `groupby`. Also it's an forward fill (`ffill`) (similar to how you drag a formula down in Excel)

```
df.groupby('VM').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
```

Result:

```
        VM  Storage Capacity MB  Memory Capacity MB  Powerstate  CPUs
0  abc1234             102400.0                4096   poweredOn     1
1  xyz1234              81920.0                4096   poweredOn     1
2  abc1234             102400.0                4096  poweredOff     1
3  xyz1234              81920.0                4096  poweredOff     1
```

Comment: Thank you -- That worked -- I also need to sum the groupby value on VM so here is final snippet:                                                                                                                                           
 merged_data.groupby('VM').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill')).groupby('VM').sum().to_csv(r'c:\temp\mergeddata_compiled.csv')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many non NA values your dataframe has. If it is just a few you can try a combination of df.ffill().bfill() or df.bfill().ffill() with just takes the non na value found and extends it forward / backward.

If there are many non na values I would suggest a workaround by looping trough the columns:

```
for col in merged_data.columns:
    first_non_na_value = merged_data[col].dropna().iloc[0]
    merged_data[col] = merged_data[col].fillna(first_non_na_value)
```